# запрос MySQL If Insert. При значении вставить несколько строк

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица со столбцами x, y, z
Нужно проверить каждую строку, что если в строчке значение поля y=i тогда добавить несколько строк с такими же значениями x, z, но с другим y, при этом проверить нет ли такой строчки уже

Пример:

```
Исходная таблица:

    x    y    z
    1    2    3
    5    6    7

Итоговая таблица:

    x    y    z
    1    2    3
    5    6    7
    1    45   3
    1    38   3
    5    68   7
    5    23   7
```

Comment: Добавте в вопрос, что пока у вас получилось.

Comment: Пример исходных данных. Желаемый результат при таких данных. Объяснение, почему так. Свои попытки, объяснения, почему так. Где всё это? А в запросе единственная сложность - как добавлять в таблицу, из которой выбираешь. Но он легкорешаемый.

Comment: `insert ignore into table(x,y,z) select x, 45, z from table where y=2` при наличии на таблице уникального ключа из колонок x,y,z. И так для каждого нового значения. либо усложнить select и заставить его генерировать такие строки из списка новых значений

Comment: спасибо,действительно все просто оказалось